# how can jsp read attribute value from its config.xml

Tags: xml, jsp

I have the following set up in my config.xml, how can I read the attribute value between the  tag? I need to read it from jsp.

```
<page-metrics>
  <metric page="test.page">
    <type default="true" name="test">
      <name>My Test Page</name>
    </type>
  </metric>
</page-metrics>
```

Comment: Is the `config.xml` specific to some framework like Spring? Or is it a custom XML file which you'd need to parse manually? If the latter is true, why exactly do you want to do it in a JSP instead of a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse XML file it should be done in the service layer. For example, you could parse XML by using DOM parser, SAX parser or any other parser.